# Disallow edit reviewing on one's own post

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I have never seen a problem with reviewing an edit on one's own post before, rather that it's a good way to shorten the review queues. It works perfectly, if just everybody handles correctly. I have now changed my mind. Today, I made an edit to an answer, as it was poorly formatted and contained rather bad grammar, and typos. The image below is a screenshot from the review of that particular edit:

[image]

Look especially at the reason that was given for why the edit was rejected, and whom rejected it. I don't understand what's wrong with my edit, so I either need a good explanation, or I push for a change to the rules of reviewing, so that one can no longer review edits on one's own posts.

This edit came a few minutes later, and at first sight, I thought the author had stolen my edit, but he/she probably knows nothing about it.

[image]

Here's a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54399799/7395227) to the post.

Comment: Some people unfortunately make stupid review decisions. But taking review on their own posts away from everyone is even more stupid. Often, the author can best judge if an edit preserves their intent and is constructive.

Comment: Following the same logic, since some users make very bad edits, we should remove the edit-not-owned-posts functionality altogether.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth Yes, of course, an author can often know that best, but it also means that they have the power to, as you said, "unfortunately make stupid review decisions". Shouldn't we then at least need one more review in addition to the author's, and if they disagree, provide a third reviewer?

Comment: @Andreas if the question was improved in the end regardless, I don't see the issue other than someone making a questionable decision earlier. I doubt it was a slight against you personally.

Comment: Plus, the review that ended up being accepted didn't touch the code, and you did. Maybe the post author didn't see anything wrong with their code and that's why they rejected your edit. Only the post author can say for certain.

Comment: @Andreas The OP will always have final say in edits to their post

Comment: @WhatsThePoint No they won't.  In cases where a post author is unambiguously making their post worse, a moderator will step in and ensure the edits are made to the post.  The author has final say over the technical substance of their post, as well as final say over subjective decisions over presentation.

Comment: @Servy I guess I should have said a non-deliberately destructive OP will have final say in the edits to their post

Comment: @WhatsThePoint It doesn't matter if it's deliberate or not.  If it's an objectively destructive action, regardless of intent, a moderator will overrule it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Disallowing the author to review the edit would just be pointless, because they have the ability to make edits without review on their own post, so if an edit that they don't want to make is approved, they'll just roll it back.  Allowing the author to review the edit is just a small convenience, and prevents reviewers from wasting their time if the OP wants to have a say in the edit, because they're going to have their say either way.